# Specs2 JsonMatchers match 'empty array'

Tags: json, scala, specs2

I have the following json string:

```
{"guid": "4bad1d9a-180f-4751-a698-4aac07b1eac7","partition":1,"roles": []}
```

I've been able to use specs2's org.specs2.matcher.JsonMatchers to enforce guid and partition, e.g.:

```
json must /("guid" -> "4bad1d9a-180f-4751-a698-4aac07b1eac7")
json must /("partition" -> 1)
```

But I cannot figure out the correct syntax to enforce that 'roles' is present and 'is an empty array'. Is this do-able?

**Edit:**

Per a commenter's question, I have tried the following:

```
json must /("roles" -> "[]")
```

which results in the following test failure:

```
[error]    {guid : 5ad4c4c5-4fdb-461b-9883-b84ff3b84610,partition : 1.0,roles : []} doesn't contain 'roles' : '[]'
```

Comment: I suppose you've tried `json must /("roles" -> "[]")`?

Comment: just when i thought there is probably no chance of finding a question like this in the whole wide internet. you have the exact same question, _and_ there are good answers, too, yaaay!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value to be tested for `roles` is of `scala.util.parsing.json.JSONArray` type so you can write:

```
json must /("roles" -> JSONArray(Nil))
```

And if that comes up a lot maybe define a value:

```
val empty = JSONArray(Nil)
json must /("roles" -> empty)
```

Comment: Just a typo in my question. The JSON is valid, the question is about syntax for ensuring that a values is an empty array using specs2 json matchers.

Comment: I could swear I'd tried that, but the proof is in the pudding. That worked (of course). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For those coming to this question looking for an answer, the answer supplied by Eric is no longer valid.

It seems the current way (`specs2 3.8`) to match an empty array would be:

```
json must /("roles").andHave(exactly[String]())
```

This is not the best way, but it's the only one I found that works and makes *some* sense when read back.

The `andHave` matches against the contents of `roles` and `exactly` with no parameters matches an empty array. The use of the `String` type parameter is there because otherwise the compiler complains it can't infer the type.